# Get access to object's method without referencing 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript

I'm exploring some code written for desktop application and it's using `ScriptControl` object to access method of a global object (which doesn't require specifying the `this` keyword). I'm wondering how this can be done without the usage of ScriptControl. Here is the sample code:

```
var i = function() {success()};

(function(f) {
    var o = {"success": function() {alert('success')}};
    f.apply(o); // fails because 'success' method is referenced inside 'f' by itself
})(i);
```

So is there any way I can access "success" method of parent without specifying the `this` keyword?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the line that fails ?

Comment: I don't understand your use case, but try this: `f(o['success']);` and in your *i* function: `var i = function(s) { s() };`

Comment: What's wrong with using `this.success()`? The only other option would be to simply overwrite that global `success` variable that `i` references.

Comment: Yeah, what's wrong with `this`?

Comment: Guys, this question is for learning purposes. I could easily do that with referencing 'this' keywords and probably would if I wrote this code. I'm just trying to figure if there is any way to do the same without using ScriptControl

Comment: @Bergi, >> _The only other option would be to simply overwrite that global success variable that i references_ --can you demostrate that in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.apply()`?

```
var i = function(obj) {obj.success()};

(function(f) {
    var o = {"success": function() {alert('success')}};
    f(o);
})(i);
```

---

Tell you what, here's another way.

```
var i = function() {i.o.success()};

(function(f) {
    var o = {"success": function() {alert('success')}};
    f.o = o;
    f();
})(i);
```

Comment: @Maximus: Of course it'll work. It just passes `o` to `f` and invokes `.success()` on it. Basic JavaScript. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2J8hn/

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that 'i' function was modified. I can't modify 'i' function.

Comment: Thanks for your variants, but you altered 'i' function again. I can't do that.

Comment: Yeah, I edited it before I saw your comment. You should probably detail all the constraints in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite that global success variable that i references:

```
var success;

var i = function() {success()};

(function(f) {
    // Assuming you have access the the scope where `success` is defined
    // which is true for the global scope in this example
    success = function() {alert('success')};
    f();
})(i);
```

However, that looks hacky. If you're designing an API, it would be better to pass the callback function as a parameter to `i`.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have access to global scope. As I understand it `ScriptControl` creates global scope and sets 'o' object as global object making 'success()' a global function - something like what `eval` function does. So I think there is no way to do the same using native JavaScript possiblities.